# Cannot find an icon at Android studio latest version

Tags: android-studio, android-xml-attribute

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaYuk.jpg)

I cannot find the button that switches the xml attribute editor and xml attribute table. This is the latest version of android studio and I am completely new to this interface. Help me out to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any difficulty with your editor, always use the Help menu.

For Android studio, il will send you here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro?utm_source=android-studio

then you click on the search button and type, "xml attribute editor" and you get:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button